# HttpClient - System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException - Server StatusCode 500

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf, asp.net-web-api

Here's my WCF service contract, one of the method sigs:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "", Method = "POST")]
public InventoryResponse Post(InventoryRequest inventoryRequest)
{
```

This REST endpoint works in fiddler when I make a POST request to that endpoint, I DO successfully get back json:

Endpoint I'm posting to: `http://localhost/Inventory/`

[image]

[image]

Headers:

[image]

However this does not and it's trying to make a call to the same url.  I end up getting back a 500 server-side error in the respnse saying "Internal Server Error" which probably means that some code failed but then how come the fiddler call works...seems like that doesn't add up.

```
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var postUri= "http://localhost/Inventory/";
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(postUri);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        inventoryResponse = client.PostAsJsonAsync("", inventoryRequest).Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<InventoryResponse>().Result;

    }
```

This error says I think that I did not get a json object back from the service:

```
    System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'InventoryResponse' from content with media type 'text/html'.

System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Error in line 1 position 70. Expecting element 'InventoryPostResponse' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EventInventory.Applications.WebService.Jetson.Responses.BulkPosting'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'Fault', namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none'.
```

Comment: Why not use a Fiddler to check what actually goes to server? I guess you just have an error page in return, which have `text/html` media type.

Comment: I just showed you that

Comment: You're showing Fiddler Composer, not actual request.

Comment: ok I just posted the request and response header info

Comment: I think there is misunderstanding. You are telling that you get `500 Internal Server Error`, but show us a successful call made (as far as I can tell) using Fiddler itself. Why not capture traffic what your `HttpClient` generates? Or there is something that doesn't allow you to do that?

Comment: are you saying to see what the client has during runtime?  I did that, doesn't tell me anything that helps.  That's where I could also see the response sending back a 500, when I looked at the client during my unit test run

Comment: Well, I can suggest you to compare carefully your requests, exact same requests should produce exact same results, but there is something that ruins your request. Use `Raw` view for Request/Response in Fiddler and notice any differences. Maybe it's your JSON request is somehow invalid in `HttpClient` case?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict Please find my update: EDIT 1. It should work with those changes.

Comment: Did you look at the response of media type 'text/html' that you are getting in your code. Within it is the problem. That html is the horrible yellow error message with red text that a .net returns when exceptions are not properly handled. -> Error: expecting json but got a horrible .net/iis html message instead.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 1:**

It seems it's some restriction of HTTPClient. I've finally resolved an issue for me. Here is my advice:

1. Change you UriTemplate in you service contract:

   ```
   [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "Inventory", Method = "POST")]
   public InventoryResponse Post(InventoryRequest inventoryRequest)
   ```
2. Change endpoint address to

   ```
   http://localhost
   ```
3. Try to hit the service with HTTPClient again:

   ```
   using (var client = new HttpClient())
   {
       var postUri= "http://localhost/";
       client.BaseAddress = new Uri(postUri);
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

       inventoryResponse = client.PostAsJsonAsync("Inventory", inventoryRequest).Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<InventoryResponse>().Result;

   }
   ```

Finally, it should work.

**Prev. answer:**

Your client doesn't send a proper request, server expects xml but client send something else (it seems that it's json and content type is text).

1. You can make a call on the client a bit differently:
   Reference at you client library with just service interfaces and data contracts (there shouldn't be service implementation, but it's ok if it's for the test). And replace your code with this:

   ```
   ChannelFactory<YourServiceInterface> myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<YourServiceInterface>("MyService"); //MyServive clinet endpoint name

   // Create a channel.
   YourServiceInterface wcfClient1 = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
   var resp = wcfClient1.Post(inventoryRequest);

   ((IClientChannel)wcfClient1).Close();
   ```

   If you care about async operation you can do it with TPL, using a Task
2. Fiddler has an option to catch every request from other clients. Do that and send us content of a request and response.
3. It's definitely something wrong with you client. You can try this code, it must work (it works for me, I've checked):

   ```
   public class WebRequestor
   {
       public void MakeCall(DividendEvents dividends, Uri uri)
       {
           var postData = Serialize(dividends);
           var request = FormWebRequest(postData, uri);

           var response = request.GetResponse();

           Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
           var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
           var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

           // Read the content of response, if you need to have to deserialize it (in the same way as Serialize method does serialization)
           string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

           reader.Close();
           dataStream.Close();
           response.Close();
       }

       private static WebRequest FormWebRequest(string postData, Uri uri)
       {
           WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
           request.Method = "POST";
           request.ContentType = "application/json";

           byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
           request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
           // Get the request stream.
           Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
           // Write the data to the request stream.
           dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
           // Close the Stream object.
           dataStream.Close();
           return request;
       }

       private static string Serialize(object data)
       {
           var stream1 = new MemoryStream();
           var testSer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(data.GetType());
           testSer.WriteObject(stream1, data);
           stream1.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
           var sreader = new StreamReader(stream1);
           var cont = sreader.ReadToEnd();
           return cont;
       }
   }
   ```

And here is the actual call:

```
        var div = new DividendEvents() {Events = new[] {1, 2, 3}, Id = "GOOGL"};
        new WebRequestor().MakeCall(div, new Uri("http://localhost:9002/Pricing/Dividends"));
```

Comment: no the server expects json, I proved it by being able to send json in fiddler and we've been allowing json all along

Comment: no I'm making a REST call, I'm not doing it that way.  The whole point of using the HttpClient is to mimic an integration test as a user making a REST call to the service endpoint

Comment: Investigate the object 
var responseRes = inventoryResponse = client.PostAsJsonAsync("", inventoryRequest).Result;
It will say you more about error, post everything it says.

Comment: that's what I've been doing but with httpclient, I looked at the request and response properties and went through that extensively and see nothing different

Comment: Do you have error handler on server side? : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23069307/3523746

Comment: @CoffeeAddict Have you tried advise from "EDIT 1" ?