# WCF dynamic json to Dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, wcf, dictionary

I'm using ASPX 4.5. 
 
The client sends one JSON object with dynamic fields (can be different each time)

```
function storeDataInSession(formData) {
    var data = {};
    data["formData"] = formData;

    $.ajax({
        url: "MY_URL/StoreFormData",
        type: "post",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log("success");
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("failure");
        }
    });
}
```

On the server side I'm trying to convert that JSON to Dictionary, but I'm getting error 500.

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    public String StoreFormData(dynamic formData) 
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Dictionary<string, string> formValues = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(formData);


        return "aaaaa";
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add error handling to you service it will help to figure out what happens wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212705/wcf-how-to-handle-errors-globally/23213446#23213446

Comment: The error: Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from MYURL

Comment: I've notice that you use dynamic. It's not allowed for WCF

Answer (score 2):

As you want to receive raw data into your method param, you have to implement your method in a way:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "form/data",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
public String StoreFormData(Stream fileContents)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileContents))
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        //here is your json, received from a client
        string jsonData = reader.ReadToEnd();

        // I think for that you case it's better to use Newtonsoft.Json library. It will allow you to parse more complex data
        //JObject data = JObject.Parse(jsonData); 

        //Dictionary<string, string> formValues = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(formData);
    }

    return "aaaaa";
}
```

In such a way you will be able to receive plain json data in the way it was formed on a client side. Then you can parse them in a way you need/want.

**EDIT 1:**

P.S. Don't forget to change UriTemplate = "form/data" to whatever you need.

**EDIT 2:**

I think that for your case it's better to use Newtonsoft.Json library. It will allow you to parse more complex data:

```
JObject data = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
```

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 problems:
1. I used dynamic as @Legart mentioned.
 
2. The parameter was a json object.

There are a working solution:

```
function storeDataInSession(formData) {
    var data = {};
    data["formData"] = JSON.stringify(formData);

    $.ajax({
        url: "MYURL/StoreFormData",
        type: "post",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log("success");
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("failure");
        }
    });
}
```

The server side:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    public String StoreFormData(string formData) 
    {        
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Dictionary<string, string> formValues = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(formData);

        string test = "test:  ";
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in formValues) 
        {
            test += String.Format(" key: {0}  value: {1} ", item.Key, item.Value);
        }



        return formData;
    }
```